# Aggregate multiple columns in Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have issues in solving the following problem.
Basically I want to find on which date a particular item(`item_code`) was sold maximum and minimum volume.

**Input DataFrame**

```
item_code, sold_date, price, volume
101,      10-12-2017, 20,    500
101,      11-12-2017, 20,    400
201,      10-12-2017, 50,    200
201,      13-12-2017, 51,    300
```

**Expected output**

Find `max` and `min` volume with sold date.I want this solution without using any `lambda` operations.

[image]

```
df.groupBy("item_code")agg(min("volume"),max("volume"))
```

the above one will help me to get `max` and `min` of volume but I want them along with respective date.

I tried my level best with udf but I could not crack it. any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Please try to post text samples instead of images. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.Updated my post @philantrovert

Comment: it din help me. I want , on which sold_date , volume  max/min for given item_code. first() returns same date to all my results.

Comment: In the groupBy clause, after you grouping it will be a list of dates so you must choose with an aggregate function between them. What aggregate function to you want to use ?. Take for example another row for id: 101, what date should be chosen ?

Comment: @dumitru updated my question. please check.

Comment: What means "along with respective date" ? . What should be the output if you add the following rows: 101,      9-12-2017, 20,    500 and 
101,      6-12-2017, 20,    500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final output you desire needs complex process. You can use the following process.

Given the input `dataframe` as

```
+---------+----------+-----+------+
|item_code|sold_date |price|volume|
+---------+----------+-----+------+
|101      |10-12-2017|20   |500   |
|101      |11-12-2017|20   |400   |
|201      |10-12-2017|50   |200   |
|201      |13-12-2017|51   |300   |
+---------+----------+-----+------+
```

You can use the following code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val tempDF = df.groupBy("item_code").agg(min("volume").as("min"),max("volume").as("max"))
tempDF.as("t2").join(df.as("t1"), col("t1.item_code") === col("t2.item_code") && col("t1.volume") === col("t2.min"), "left")
  .select($"t2.item_code", $"t2.max", concat_ws(",", $"t2.item_code", $"t2.min", $"t1.sold_date").as("min"))
  .join(df.as("t3"), col("t3.item_code") === col("t2.item_code") && col("t3.volume") === col("t2.max"), "left")
  .select($"min", concat_ws(",", $"t3.item_code", $"t2.max", $"t3.sold_date").as("max"))
  .show(false)
```

which is going to give you the `dataframe` you desire

```
+------------------+------------------+
|min               |max               |
+------------------+------------------+
|101,400,11-12-2017|101,500,10-12-2017|
|201,200,10-12-2017|201,300,13-12-2017|
+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Seems to be quite expensive process..... takes lot of time even against 200mb of dataset.

Comment: joins are always expensive :)

Answer (score 0):

Best approach here is to create a new index (ie column) to the Dataframe as a result of concatenation of the columns required for sorting. Implement a smart sorting on String based new index so that the results are still sorted numerically but you carry along the information of Date and actually whatever you need to retrieve as part of the query.

That way there is no need for JOINs.